# Custom styling for cytoscape nodes

Tags: cytoscape.js

I would like to add some custom styles to the nodes in my cytoscape graph based on some condition. Is that possible?Specifically, I would like to add multiple borders with inner border as percentage circle. I am open to using predefined percentages. Something like below: 
[image: Cytoscape custom node]

Is this possible? Would be great if someone can suggest a work around.
I can get a single border using the border properties in cystoscape.js. In plain css3, this can be done using pseudo elements, but not sure how that works in cytoscape.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cytoscape.js does not support pseudo elements.

If you want custom graphics, you can use background images.  If you want them dynamically generated, you can use a function style property value that returns the image URI.  You can use the canvas API to create the image.

The pie styles are similar to the purple section in your image, but you have a hollow portion -- so it's probably best to generate the image.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a node, you can add extra information ( API is great )

```
NEWnode.push({
            group: "nodes",
            data: {typeCss: 'css1', etc: 'etc'},
            // group: css1,
            // classes: css1
        });

// add node
cy.add(NEWnode);
```

and get/parse the node informations

```
cy.nodes().each(function(i) {

}
```